# Date picker not properly updating date objects

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, datetime

I'm utilizing a date-time picker found here https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker to grab/update a 'beginning' and 'end' date object (see `selectedMoments` on TypeScript code) for a date selector. However, whenever I select a new date and trigger the function `dateTimePickerActivate()` (see `(dateTimeChange)=` on HTML code) I get a TypeError (see error 1 below) and the new date can only be found in the hidden object property `_pendingValue` (see error 2 below), which doesn't update the actual value of the date objects.

How can I fix these to properly update the `selectedMoments` object array?

HTML:

```
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
  <input matInput placehold="Time Range (Optional):" [selectMode]="'range'" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dateTimePicker" [owlDateTime]="dateTimePicker" [formControl]="selectedMoments" (dateTimeChange)="dateTimePickerActivate()">
  <owl-date-time showSecondsTimer="'true'" hour12Timer="'true'" #dateTimePicker></owl-date-time>
</mat-form-field>
```

TypeScript:

```
// Date & Time Stored Value
// Note: Month starts at 0, so ex: February would == 1
public selectedMoments = [new Date(2018, 1, 12, 10, 30), new Date(2018, 3, 21, 20, 30)];

dateTimePickerActivate() {
  console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this.selectedMoments));
  console.log(this.selectedMoments);
}
```

Errors:

1) `html ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function` in regards to `(dateTimeChange)="dateTimePickerActivate()"`

2)

[image: pic1]
[image: pic2]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for updating the date (albeit a bit hacky), however I still have not found a way to fix the first error.

HTML:

`(dateTimeChange)="dateTimePicked(dateTimePicker)"`

TypeScript:

```
dateTimePicked(selectedDate) {
  const dateRangeObject = {
    // First date
    from: selectedDate.selecteds[0],
    // Second date
    to: selectedDate.selecteds[1],
  };

  console.log(dateRangeObject);
  // do something with dates here...
}
```